# Go through a text file, replacing all instances of a variable with its definition / contents

Tags: c, variables, replace, makefile, text-files

I've hit a mental block on a project I'm doing. I want to go through a file and replace all instances of variables with their contents, or value. I have a data structure which contains the variables, and I have the text file in question assigned to a file pointer.

The data structure holding the variables consists of a key (variable name) and data (variable definition):

```
// Preceeds the creation of a map to store the variable names and values
struct VarMap {
    char data[1000];
    char key[1000];
};
```

This definition is in the header file for my project. The following is an example of the text files with which I am dealing with:

```
# A Makefile to build our 'calcmarks' project

C99     =  cc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror


calcmarks : calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -o calcmarks \
                  calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o -lm


calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c calcmarks.c

globals.o : globals.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c globals.c

readmarks.o : readmarks.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c readmarks.c

correlation.o : correlation.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c correlation.c
```

As you may already be aware from the code above, I am writing a program which can implement a small subset of the program *make*. The variables in the above text file are preceded with a dollar '$' sign, and the name of the variable is placed between parentheses '()', as in $(C99) or $(CFLAGS) in the above example; though other variable names may exist.

I've already written part of the program to process these variables, the final part of this function not being finished yet but which I hope to use to perform the actual "variable substitution":

```
#include "globals.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// Store and replace all variables used in the makefile
void processVariables(FILE* spData) {

    // Initialise the counting variable buffer to hold the file line by line
    varCount = 0;
    char buffer[10000];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        // Skip commented lines (preceede by hash '#')
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' ; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '=') {
                // Increment if line with equals sign is found
                varCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Debugging print statement
    printf ("varCount has counted %d equals signs.\n\n" , varCount);

    // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount + 4];
    int j = 0;
    rewind(spData);
    // Parse the makefile/bakefile (what is it even now) and store the variable names and assignments
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        char* p = strstr(buffer,"=");
        if (p) {
            *p++ = 0;
            // If copy size is too small, change the final number in the function
            strncpy(variables[j].key, buffer,1000);
            strncpy(variables[j].data, p,1000);
            j++;
        }
    }

    // Appending the general variables to the variable array
    strcpy(variables[varCount].key , "PID");
    strcpy(variables[varCount].data , "getpid()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 1].key , "PPID");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 1].data , "getppid()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 2].key , "PWD");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 2].data , "getcwd()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 3].key , "RAND");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 3].data , "rand()");

    // Debugging print statement (All code above this point is correct)
    printf("List of all variables as they stand here:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < varCount + 4; i++) {
        printf("Key: %s, Value: %s\n" , variables[i].key , variables[i].data);
    }

    // Replacing the variables
    // Go through the file and re-write it line by line, keep calling rewind(spData);
    // and parse through the file until there are no more '$' signs
    rewind(spData);
    char copyStream[10000];
    bool noDollarSigns = false;
    // While there are still dollar signs in the file, indicating more variable substitution needs to occur
    while (noDollarSigns == false) {
        while (fgets(copyStream , sizeof(copyStream) , spData) != NULL) {

        }
    }


}
```

As you can see, the final 2 nested 'while's is the space in which I was going to perform the actual variable substitution. The general variables you can see are variables which the program will substitute into every single makefile processed.

And the *main* function for context:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char filepath[1000];
    printf("Enter the filepath of the Bakefile or bakefile: ");
    scanf("%s" , filepath);
    FILE* spData;
    spData = fopen(filepath , "r");
    if (spData == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    processVariables(spData);

    fclose(spData);
    return 0;
}
```

Calling the main function with the processVariables function as written and all the header files up to date, with the makefile outlined above, gives the following output:

```
Enter the filepath of the Bakefile or bakefile: /Users/Admin/Documents/Makefiles/Test1.txt
varCount has counted 2 equals signs.

List of all variables as they stand here:
Key: C99     , Value:   cc -std=c99

Key: CFLAGS  , Value:   -Wall -pedantic -Werror

Key: PID, Value: getpid()
Key: PPID, Value: getppid()
Key: PWD, Value: getcwd()
Key: RAND, Value: rand()
```

The first 2 variables are specific to the makefile in question, while the other 4 are generic and to be substituted into all makefiles.

I've already asked many questions here for help on my project and all responses so far have been extremely helpful - thank you very much!

So basically:

**How do I write the code to go through a texfile and substitute all instances of variables with their definitions given in my data structure? If such code should not be written in the processVariables function, where should this code go in my program?**

**EDIT 1:**
@fotang provided a semi-complete segment of code, which I have inserted and slightly modified to correct here and there. Here is the new *processVariables* function with his code inserted:

```
void processVariables(FILE* spData) {

    // Initialise the counting variable buffer to hold the file line by line
    varCount = 0;
    char buffer[10000];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        // Skip commented lines (preceede by hash '#')
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n' ; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '=') {
                // Increment if line with equals sign is found
                varCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Debugging print statement
    printf ("varCount has counted %d equals signs.\n\n" , varCount);

    // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount + 4];
    int j = 0;
    rewind(spData);
    // Parse the makefile/bakefile (what is it even now bruh) and store the variable names and assignments
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        char* p = strstr(buffer , "=");
        if (p) {
            *p++ = 0;
            // If copy size is too small, change the final number in the function
            strncpy(variables[j].key, buffer,1000);
            strncpy(variables[j].data, p,1000);

            // Get rid of any trailing newline characters in the data
            char* newline;
            if ((newline = strchr(variables[j].data, '\n')) != NULL)
                *newline = '\0';

            j++;
        }
    }

    // Appending the general variables to the variable array
    strcpy(variables[varCount].key , "PID");
    strcpy(variables[varCount].data , "getpid()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 1].key , "PPID");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 1].data , "getppid()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 2].key , "PWD");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 2].data , "getcwd()");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 3].key , "RAND");
    strcpy(variables[varCount + 3].data , "rand()");

    // Debugging print statement
    printf("List of all variables as they stand here:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < varCount + 4; i++) {
        printf("Key: %s, Value: %s\n" , variables[i].key , variables[i].data);
    }

    // Replacing the variables
    // Go through the file and re-write it line by line
    // parse through the file until there are no more '$' signs
    FILE* outputPtr = fopen("/Users/Admin/Documents/Makefiles/Output.txt","w");
    rewind(spData);
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        // Comment lines need no variable substitution so we print them as written
        if (buffer[0] == '#'){
            fputs(buffer,outputPtr);
            continue;
        }
        // Copying the buffer character by character until a dollar '$' sign is reached
        char* p = buffer;
        while (*p) {
            if (*p != '$') {
                fputc(*p++ , outputPtr);
                continue;
            }
            p++;

            if(*p != '('){
                fputc(*p++ , outputPtr);
                continue;
            }
            // Get the variable name (key)
            char *s = ++p;
            char key[1000];
            while(*s != ')') s++;
            strncpy(key, p, s - p);
            key[s - p] = 0;
            p = s + 1;
            // Fetch the contents of the variable from the structure and substitute
            for(int i = 0; i < varCount + 4; i++)
                if(strcmp(variables[i].key, key)){
                    fprintf(outputPtr, "%s", variables[i].data);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However if this function is now called on a textile with the following text: (filename is Text1.txt)

```
# A Makefile to build our 'calcmarks' project

# Variable Declarations
C99     =  cc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror


# Command lines
calcmarks : calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -o calcmarks \
                  calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o -lm


calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c calcmarks.c

globals.o : globals.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c globals.c

readmarks.o : readmarks.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c readmarks.c

correlation.o : correlation.c calcmarks.h
       $(C99) $(CFLAGS) -c correlation.c

varTest:
       $(PID) $(PPID) $(PWD) $(RAND)
```

This is the following output file contents:

```
# A Makefile to build our 'calcmarks' project

# Variable Declarations
C99     =  cc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror


# Command lines
calcmarks : calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99 -o calcmarks \
                  calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o -lm


calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99 -c calcmarks.c

globals.o : globals.c calcmarks.h
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99 -c globals.c

readmarks.o : readmarks.c calcmarks.h
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99 -c readmarks.c

correlation.o : correlation.c calcmarks.h
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99 -c correlation.c

varTest:
         cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99   cc -std=c99
```

As you can see, every variable has been replaced with the only the contents of the first variable in the structure *variable*.

**EDIT 2:**
Replacing `strcmp()` with `!strcmp()` in the final *if* block produces the following output:

```
# A Makefile to build our 'calcmarks' project

# Variable Declarations
C99     =  cc -std=c99
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -pedantic -Werror


# Command lines
calcmarks : calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o
                         calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o -lm


calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h

globals.o : globals.c calcmarks.h

readmarks.o : readmarks.c calcmarks.h

correlation.o : correlation.c calcmarks.h

varTest:
       getpid() getppid() getcwd() rand()
```

As you can see, this time, all variables are removed without substitution except for the 4 generic appended variables.

Comment: Please provide a short example of the `Test1.txt` file.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The 2nd piece of code above, the `calcmarks` makefile, contains the same contents as `Test1.txt`.

Comment: Your code looks more or less correct, except that the breaking down the keys and values is wrong, you need to get rid of the trailing and leading spaces. Now for your actual question. You need to write another function that rpocesses each line of your file and if it finds a string like `"$(foo)"` and if `"foo"` is one of keys in `variables` array it should be substituted by `"bar"` where `"bar"` iks the corresponding value.

Comment: The reason why only the first variable is used, is because you are typing (strcmp...) instead of (!strcmp...).

Comment: @fotang Ok I've tried it with and without the exclamation mark in the code segment which I appended to the question, without the '!' it does exactly as I wrote above, with the '!' it removes all the variables without substitution, except the 4 generic variables which I appended to the variable array.

Comment: I edited the question to add the result of adding the '!' to the `strcmp` function.

Comment: A likely explanation: when keys were saved, the keyname included terminating blanks (' '). When searching, however, the search key excludes the blanks. Solution: while saving the keys, trim off the surrounding spaces.

Comment: I've updated my response to add sample code for removing blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach has been mentioned in the comments section. Open a new file, scan the "Makefile" again, and substitute the variables, writing the substituted output into the new file. Let the output file be called `/tmp/output`. Here some code (untested):

**Update**: @DanielPryden raised 2 concerns in the comments section regarding the dangers of simply copying and pasting this answer. I try to address that inside the loop that starts at "char *p=buffer; while(*p){". Of course, anyone doing anything serious would use a lexical analyser such as flex and store the keys in an AVL tree or some such.

```
 FILE *output=fopen("/tmp/output","w");
rewind(spData);
while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
    if (buffer[0] == '#'){
        fputs(buffer,output);
        continue;
    }
    char *p=buffer;
    while(*p){
        if(*p!='$'){
            fputc(output, *p++);
            continue;
        }
        p++;
        if(*p!='('){
            fputc(output, *(p-1)); // bring back '$'
            fputc(output, *p++);
            continue;
        }
        // grab variable name (key)
        char *s=++p;
        #define KEYSIZE 1000;
        char key[KEYSIZE+1]; // you may want to dynamically allocate this (using malloc or strdup after grabbing the key);
        while(*s && *s!=')')
            s++;
        if(*s==0){ // didnt find closing ')'
            fputs("Unmatched '('", stderr);
            exit(-1);
        }
        if((s-p)>KEYSIZE){
            // string inside $() is longer than KEYSIZE. what do you want to do? I'll use just KEYSIZE chars.
            s=p+KEYSIZE;
        }
        strncpy(key,p,s-p);
        key[s-p]=0;
        p=s+1;
        // fetch the value for substitution
        for(int i=0; i<varCount;i++)
            if(!strcmp(variables[i].key, key)){
                fprintf(output,"%s", variables[i].data);
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Update: strip blanks before saving key:

```
    char* p = strstr(buffer , "=");
    if (p) {
        *p++ = 0;
       // **start of update**: Strip away surrounding blanks --------
         char *s=buffer;
         while (*s && *s== ' ') s++; // remove leading blanks
         if(*s){
               // Remove terminating blanks
               char *t=s;
                while(*t && *t!=' ') t++;
                *t=0;
          }
          memcpy(buffer, s, strlen(s));
       // **end of update** -- finished stripping surrounding blanks
        // If copy size is too small, change the final number in the function
        strncpy(variables[j].key, buffer,1000);
        strncpy(variables[j].data, p,1000);
```

Comment: Many thanks fotang! I've updated the question with your answer, which I tested. There are still a few issues, though.

Comment: Compare the keys with (!strcmp()), not (strcmp()). You left out  '!' .

Comment: Thank you so much @fotang, you've been an incredible help. Finally that part of my project is finished :)

Comment: @fotang: the code in this answer is a good pointer in the right direction, but since the OP (and probably others) will likely copy/paste it without necessarily understanding it, I would recommend fixing a couple of the more glaring bugs. Specifically, (1) it looks like any bare `$` character will just get eaten, and (2) it looks like this code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow on the `key` variable, which is stack-allocated and thus may be exploitable for arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @DanielPryden That's very true! I'll edit the answer.